# data-binding, IDataErrorInfo and complex properties naming

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

lets say I have MyClass.cs in which I have a property called Name, then I have my viewModel which inherits IDataErrorInfo, where I created multible instances of MyClass in this viewModel and added them all to an ObservableCollection< MyClass> , this collection will be the ItemsSource of a DataGrid , and surly one of it's DataGridTextColumn is bound to  Name property, this wrks really good as in the following XAML

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  Name}" Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

all good , now I need to supply a column name for the IDataErrorInfo, as follows

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get 
        { 
           string error = String.Empty;
           switch (columnName)
           {
               case "WhatToPutHere":
                   error = validateName();
                   return error;
               default:
                   throw new ApplicationException("Wrong Property name being validated");
           }
        }
    }
```

the problem is , I don't have this "Name" property here in  my viewModel , it is there on MyClass.cs , so I don't know what to supply the IDataErrorInfo Column name with , I tried Name and MyClass.Name both didn't work out , any suggestions ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out , I had to implement IDataErorInfo there on MyClass.cs not on the viewModel

Answer (score 0):

The name of the property. In this case it's `Name`

Comment: it is not working, I don't have a property called Name, it is a field of MyClass which I'm just creating an instance of it here where I'm implementing the IDataErrorInfo , so there is NO such a property

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure what to put there, why not put a test line of code such as msgbox(columnname).  Then run your application (or part of it) and see what pops up.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what I mean by not sure what to put there is : I already tested with "MyClass.Name" and with "Name", both not working